# Recursive-FFT Algorithm in CLRS

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

In this FFT algorithm (as per CLRS), in line number 4, shouldn't the angle be $-2\pi i/n$ and not $+2\pi i/n$?

[image: Recursive FFT Algorithm as in CLRS]

The same algorithm is used in cp-algorithms as well, but in python, `numpy.fft.fft` uses $-2\pi i/n$ as the angle. Can someone explain which algorithm is correct and which is wrong?

Comment: It's a matter of convention. Some people use the one convention, some use the other one.

Comment: I'm a bit new to the concept. Can you please elaborate? Because the computed DFT of the vector will be different in both cases, isn't it?

Comment: Some people define it with $e^{2\pi i/n}$, others with $e^{-2\pi i/n}$. It's not an important point.

Comment: Okay thank you!